# Vuejs: How to implement popover for each dropdown-items

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to have information text to be shown to the user when they hover the dropdown-items. A unique one for each dropdown. I'm using bootstrap-vue, I have a loop for the dropdown-items

```
<b-dropdown :text="currentColorType">
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="colorType in colorTypes"
    :key="colorType.id"
    :value="colorType.name">{{colorType.name}}</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
<b-popover target="id" placement="bottom" triggers="hover blur">
    <div>Information Text Here</div>
</b-popover>
```

Is there an option to attach id dynamically to  so that that can be given as target in . Tried

```
id="colorType.name"
id="`${colorType.name}`"
```

but didn't work. Also not sure if it would even be triggered even if I'm able to attach the id. Is there a better way to show info on dropdown-item hover ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the popover directive `v-b-popover` instead of `<b-popover>`.
This will allow you to directly attach the popover to `<b-dropdown-item>`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      colorTypes: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Blue'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Red'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Green'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown text="Colors">
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="colorType in colorTypes" :key="colorType.id" :value="colorType.name" v-b-popover.hover="colorType.name">
      {{ colorType.name }}
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

### Example with HTML inside the popover

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      colorTypes: [{
          id: 1,
          color: 'Blue',
          name: '<b class="text-primary">Blue<b>'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          color: 'Red',
          name: '<b class="text-danger">Red<b>'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          color: 'Green',
          name: '<b class="text-success">Green<b>'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h5>Using the HTML modifier</h5>
  <b-dropdown text="Colors">
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="colorType in colorTypes" :key="colorType.id" :value="colorType.name" v-b-popover.hover.html="colorType.name">
      {{ colorType.color }}
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
  <hr />
  <h5>Using an object</h5>
  <b-dropdown text="Colors">
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="colorType in colorTypes" :key="colorType.id" :value="colorType.name" v-b-popover.hover="{ content: colorType.name, html: true }">
      {{ colorType.color }}
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to give html in v-b-popover, its given in their documentation - https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/popover. But  it doesn.t seems to work giving html: true. Instead of Blue I wish to have html there

Comment: @theFrontEndDev I've added another snippet which shows two ways of rendering HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to bind some prop of element to

`id` of `<b-dropdown>`

and use `v-for` for `<b-popover>` too.

eg:

```
<b-dropdown :text="currentColorType">
  <b-dropdown-item 
   v-for="colorType in colorTypes"
   :key="colorType.id"
   :id="colorType.id"
   :value="colorType.name"
  >
    {{colorType.name}}
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>

<b-popover 
 v-for="(eachType, i) in colorTypes" 
 :key="i" 
 :target="eachType.id" 
 placement="bottom" 
 triggers="hover blur"
>
  <div>Information Text Here</div>
</b-popover>
```